# Error when I building my code

Tags: c++, raspberry-pi3

I had some problems with my C++ code on my Raspberry when I building the code. The code consist to take and send data from the Arduino from the sensor.

Thus I think that the problem cannot come from the Arduino because the code of the Arduino worked with a program Python but for certain reasons I need to use C++ I shall like to know how to solve my problem I am a little bit pressed for time because it is a university project.

So this is my code:

```
#include "SerialPort.h" //My library

SerialPort::SerialPort() //Constructor
{
    this->numCon = open("/dev/ttyACM0", O_RDWR| O_NOCTTY ); //ttyACM0 arduino port

    this->connected = false;

    struct termios tty;
    struct termios tty_old;
    memset (&tty, 0, sizeof tty);

    /* Error Handling */
    if ( tcgetattr ( this->numCon, &tty ) != 0 ) {
        std::cout << "Error " << errno << " from tcgetattr: " << strerror(errno) << std::endl;
        return;
    }

    /* Save old tty parameters */
    tty_old = tty;

    /* Set Baud Rate */
    cfsetospeed (&tty, (speed_t)B9600);
    cfsetispeed (&tty, (speed_t)B9600);

    /* Setting other Port Stuff */
    tty.c_cflag     &=  ~PARENB;            // Make 8n1
    tty.c_cflag     &=  ~CSTOPB;
    tty.c_cflag     &=  ~CSIZE;
    tty.c_cflag     |=  CS8;

    tty.c_cflag     &=  ~CRTSCTS;           // no flow control
    tty.c_cc[VMIN]   =  1;                  // read doesn't block
    tty.c_cc[VTIME]  =  5;                  // 0.5 seconds read timeout
    tty.c_cflag     |=  CREAD | CLOCAL;     // turn on READ & ignore ctrl lines

    /* Make raw */
    cfmakeraw(&tty);

    /* Flush Port, then applies attributes */
    tcflush(this->numCon, TCIFLUSH );
    if ( tcsetattr (this->numCon, TCSANOW, &tty ) != 0) {
        std::cout << "Error " << errno << " from tcsetattr" << std::endl;
        return;
    }

    this->connected = true;
}

SerialPort::~SerialPort() //Destructor
{
    if (this->connected) {
        this->connected = false;
    }
}  

char* SerialPort::readSerialPort()
{
    int n = 0, spot = 0;
    char buf = '\0';

    /* Whole response*/
    char response[1024];
    memset(response, '\0', sizeof response);

    do {
        n = read(this->numCon, &buf, 1 );
        sprintf( &response[spot], "%c", buf );
        spot += n;
    } while( buf != '\r' && n > 0);

    if (n < 0) {
        std::cout << "Error reading: " << strerror(errno) << std::endl;
    }
    else if (n == 0) {
        std::cout << "Read nothing!" << std::endl;
    }
    else {
        std::cout << "Response: " << response << std::endl;
    }

    return response;
}

void SerialPort::writeSerialPort(unsigned char cmd[])
{
    int n_written = 0, spot = 0;
    do {
        n_written = write(this->numCon, &cmd[spot], 1 );
        spot += n_written;
    } while (cmd[spot-1] != '\r' && n_written > 0);
}  

bool SerialPort::isConnected()
{
    return this->connected;
}
```

And this is the library (SerialPort.h):

```
#ifndef SERIALPORT_H
#define SERIALPORT_H

#include <stdio.h>      // standard input / output functions
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>     // string function definitions
#include <unistd.h>     // UNIX standard function definitions
#include <fcntl.h>      // File control definitions
#include <errno.h>      // Error number definitions
#include <termios.h>    // POSIX terminal control definitions
#include <iostream>
class SerialPort
{
    private:
       int numCon;
       bool connected;

    public:
        SerialPort();
        ~SerialPort();

        char* readSerialPort();
        void writeSerialPort(unsigned char cmd[]);
        bool isConnected();
};

#endif // SERIALPORT_H
```

The error:

```
pi@Lux:~/PROJET $ g++  SerialPort.cpp -o SerialPort.out
SerialPort.cpp: In member function ‘char* SerialPort::readSerialPort()’:
SerialPort.cpp:63:7: warning: address of local variable ‘response’ returned 
[-Wreturn-local-addr]
  char response[1024];
        ^~~~~~~~
/usr/lib/gcc/arm-linux-gnueabihf/6/../../../arm-linux-gnueabihf/crt1.o : Dans 
la fonction « _start » :
(.text+0x34) : référence indéfinie vers « main »
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
pi@Lux:~/PROJET $ ./SerialPort.cpp
./SerialPort.cpp: ligne 2: $'\r' : commande introuvable
./SerialPort.cpp: ligne 3: erreur de syntaxe près du symbole inattendu « $'\r' »
'/SerialPort.cpp: ligne 3: `SerialPort::SerialPort()
```

Comment: Can you add the error you're getting on execution to your post?

Comment: Do you get unexpected output? What is the actual and expected output? Or do the program crash? For that you need to debug it.

Comment: yes sure.                                                                        
./SerialPort.cpp: ligne 2: $'\r' : commande introuvable
./SerialPort.cpp: ligne 3: erreur de syntaxe près du symbole inattendu « $'\r' »
'/SerialPort.cpp: ligne 3: `SerialPort::SerialPort()

Comment: So not an error *executing* your code. An error *building* your code. Please copy the errors, as text and in full and complete, and then pasted it into the body of the question. Preferably with English language settings when building since most here speaks English and not French (it seems). And please [read about how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: thanks some programmer dude, i had the error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's take the first error, which isn't really an error but "just" a warning that you do something bad:

```
SerialPort.cpp: In member function ‘char* SerialPort::readSerialPort()’:
SerialPort.cpp:63:7: warning: address of local variable ‘response’ returned
```

In the `SerialPort::readSerialPort` function the variable `response` is a local variable. Its lifetime and scope is that of the function call. When the function ends, so does the lifetime of the variable. It will, in a way, cease to exist. Returning a pointer to this variable will immediately make the pointer invalid.

If you want to treat the data you read as a string, then use a string data-type. Like [`std::string`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string) in standard C++, and [`String`](https://www.arduino.cc/reference/en/language/variables/data-types/stringobject/) in Arduino.

---

The second error is because your code does not have a `main` function. The global `main` function is the entry-point to all standard C++ programs.